# Using matriphe/larinfo on Laravel 5.4 project - getting class not found error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to use this package in a Laravel 5.4 project (php 7.1 x86 on Windows 7 via XAMPP): https://github.com/matriphe/larinfo

As per instruction, I've loaded the package onto my project using:

> composer require matriphe/larinfo

Then I've added the service provider in `config/app.php` like this:

> Matriphe\Larinfo\LarinfoServiceProvider::class,

and added the Facade alias like this:

> 'Larinfo' => Matriphe\Larinfo\LarinfoFacade::class,

In a test route, I've tried to use it like this:

```
return \Larinfo::getInfo();
```

When I visit the test route; I am getting this error:

```
Class 'Larinfo' not found
```

When I tried to use it like this:

```
return Matriphe\Larinfo\Larinfo::getInfo();
```

I get this error:

```
Non-static method Matriphe\Larinfo\Larinfo::getInfo() should not be called statically
```

Any ideas why this might not be working? I've already tried running `composer dump-auto` and it hasn't helped.

How do you use this package? What am I missing?

Comment: Have you looked at the source to see how the function is used?

Comment: also have you tried something like `$info = new Larinfo; dd($info->getInfo())` ?

Comment: How did you solve this problem? I am having the same.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for your comment. I've updated the README in the package.

For the usage, just simply use the Facade like this.

```
$larinfo = Larinfo::getInfo(); // For all info
$hostIpinfo = Larinfo::getHostIpinfo(); // For host info
$clientIpinfo = Larinfo::getClientIpinfo(); // For client info only
$serverInfoSoftware = Larinfo::getServerInfoSoftware(); // For server software info only
$serverInfoHardware = Larinfo::getServerInfoHardware(); // For hardware info only
$uptime = Larinfo::getUptime(); // For uptime info only
$serverInfo = Larinfo::getServerInfo(); // For server info only
$databaseInfo = Larinfo::getDatabaseInfo(); // For database info only
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. This is now working. P.S. if you are on windows, you will get this error `Class 'COM' not found`. Can you update the `README.md` to include a note about enabling this extension to get the script working?

Comment: Okay, I have enabled `extension=php_com_dotnet.dll` and now I am getting this error: `Method getModel not present.` - new issue submitted - https://github.com/matriphe/larinfo/issues/2

Comment: Thanks for the report. I haven't tested it in Windows, since I'm using Mac. will try it in the Windows machine.